# Log console on remotely

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, remote-access

Is there a way to log a console session on remotely.  I do not want to access the computer myself, rather allow someone who is sitting there to access it without giving them the username/password.

- I have VPN access to the network and admin access to the computer
- Running on a Win 2K3 AD network
- The computer in question is on XP SP3

** EDIT: To clarify

1. I am physically in location A
2. The computer is physically in location B
3. Someone else is physically in location B with the computer
4. I want to log the computer on for that someone else *without* giving them the credentials (username/pass).  That is, I want them to call me and say "log it on please," then I will enter the credentials from location A and the computer will log on locally at location B.

Comment: Why don't you access it, log on, and then not touch it?

Comment: I want to be able to do it _remotely_, ie when I have no physical access to the machine.

Comment: Right, just use a remote client to log in... This is not so complicated

Comment: ... I thought I made this clear in the question.  I do _not_ want to use the computer, I want to let _someone else_ who is in physically in front of the computer use it while I am not physically in front of the computer.  A remote client will log me in to the session and lock a local user out AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, log in as that user via Remote Desktop. You may *disconnect*, but the session must remain logged in.

Then log in as yourself (over a second connection if needed), or use `psexec` to run the command below remotely if the firewall allows "file sharing" connections to the XP machine.

Now run

```
tscon <id> /dest:console /password:<passwd>
```

replacing `<id>` with the first session's ID (you can get it from `qwinsta`), and `<passwd>` with the user's password.

If you get "Permission denied" or related errors, or if you cannot give the password on the command line, use [`psexec -s`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to gain *SeTcbPrivilege*:

```
psexec -s tscon <id> /dest:console
```

```
psexec \\winxpbox -s tscon <id> /dest:console
```

---

Note: You might be *required* to use `psexec`, in fact. I had forgotten that XP only allows a single active connection by default.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the clear explanation of all the steps.